# Query problem in Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gqlquery

I am very new to sql and more over GQL used in Google app engine. I have managed to push my data to the Google servers but I am not able to figure out a way to query from the entities I've loaded to the datastrore.

Here's the problem, i want to query only the names and numbers of a user's contacts marked by user id apart from other columns like given below,

```
Name Number       User_id Country    
Rob  0065114146   654351  singapore
Mark 0065132411   654351  singapore
Tina 0065221916   846611  singapore
Nick 0065214126   846611  singapore
```

This is my Models.py file in which I have my MyContacts Entity definition,

```
Class MyContacts(db.Model): 
  Name = db.StringProperty(required=True) 
  Number = db.PhoneNumberProperty(required=True) 
  User_id = db.IntegerProperty(required=True) 
  Country = db.StringProperty()
```

I am taking the user id as input from the UI but I am not able to figure out a way to bring up the data using the query. Please if any one can help me coin the query in GQL it would be a great help for me.
I've tried all sorts like `SELECT * FROM MyContacts WHERE __key__ = KEY('user_id',654351)` but i get nothing.

Please help me out.

Comment: It would help to see your model definition.

Comment: Yes, we really need to see your model for MyContacts to say anything useful.

Comment: This is my Models.py file under which I have my MyContacts entity,

Class MyContacts(db.Model):
  Name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
  Number = db.PhoneNumberProperty(required=True)
  User_id = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
  Country = db.StringProperty()

Answer (score 1):

Since User_id is an IntegerProperty, you need to query like this:

```
db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM MyContacts WHERE User_id = :1", some_int)
```

or equivalently with a query:

```
MyContacts.all().filter('User_id =', some_int)
```

Note that if 'User_id' is taken from a Users API User object, you should not be casting it to an int - it's not guaranteed to fit in 64 bits, so you should either be storing it as a string or as a UserProperty.

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve only the two columns "Name" and "Number" instead of all the columns as I want to show only the name and his number on the UI, so that I can get faster response.

Comment: No - entities are always returned as a whole. You can denormalize into separate tables, but it's really not necessary for a model as small as this one.